# Shortening a jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am novice to jQuery and have the code below repeating itself over and over again. Is there a way I can shorten these codes and make them into one statement? What the code does, is get the value of a checked radio button and display the value in a dive with a certain class. I have multiple groups of such radio buttons (with different names) and the when the user make a selection, the users choice is displayed in a div. The code works, but I would like to shorten the code if possible. The code looks redundant.

Here is the code:

```
    // To show default Selection
    $(".designLayout").html($('input[name="designLayout"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="designLayout"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".designLayout").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".printRun").html($('input[name="printRun"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="printRun"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".printRun").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".printedSides").html($('input[name="printedSides"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="printedSides"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".printedSides").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".finishedSize").html($('input[name="finishedSize"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="finishedSize"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".finishedSize").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".paperWeight").html($('input[name="paperWeight"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="paperWeight"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".paperWeight").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".refining").html($('input[name="refining"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="refining"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".refining").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".processing").html($('input[name="processing"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="processing"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".processing").html(($(this).val()));
    });

    // To show default Selection
    $(".deliveryMethod").html($('input[name="deliveryMethod"]:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name="deliveryMethod"]').on('click change', function() {
        $(".deliveryMethod").html(($(this).val()));
    });
```

Comment: Combine a loop with string concatenation.

Comment: I think you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should belong to **[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/`)**

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't aware of the code review community. I will post it there. Thank you

Comment: No, this is not suitable for codereview. Codereview is for self-contained working, complete code. If you expand this stub into a working code, feel we would love to review it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using same string for `name` and `class`, You can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to bind the `change` event handler.

```
//Use multiple selectors
$('input[name="paperWeight"], input[name="finishedSize"]').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked){ //Check the element is checked 
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); //Get name attribute
        $("." + name).html(this.value); //set the value on desired html element
    }        
}).change(); //trigger on page load to set the default value
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write function like this

```
function sample(name) {
 $("."+name).html($('input[name='+name+']:checked').val());
    // Change on Click
    $('input[name='+name+']').on('click change', function() {
        $("."+name).html(($(this).val()));
    });
}

sample('designLayout');
sample('printRun');
```

You proceed like that.